# Akami auth.net upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authorize.net, activemerchant

I am using [ActiveMerchant::Billing::AuthorizeNetGateway](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/Shopify/active_merchant/ActiveMerchant/Billing/AuthorizeNetGateway) for authorize.net payment.

How can I upgrade for Akami and how can I change the URL ?

Answer (score 0):

The ActiveMerchant gem already uses Akamai SureRoute transaction URLs for Auth.net:

https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/blob/master/lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/authorize_net.rb#L8

As directed here:

http://www.authorize.net/support/akamaifaqs/?utm_campaign=May%202016%20Technical%20Updates%20for%20Developers.htm&utm_medium=email&utm_source=Eloqua#newurls